# VBA clear content in cell range, except for sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba

How should write the code so that it skips sheet1?

```
Sub Clear_All()

Dim Ws As Worksheet

For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  Ws.Range("A11:F800").ClearContents
Next Ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way would be something like

```
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then Ws.Range("A11:F800").ClearContents
Next Ws
```

but, if `Sheet1` were *already* the left-most tab in the workbook then you could do so more simply

```
   Dim i as Long
   For i = 2 to Worksheets.Count
       Worksheets(i).Range("A11:F800").ClearContents
   Next i
```